# Zebra ZT410 ZPL User input

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, barcode-printing

I'm working with Zebra ZT410 and would like to create a template label in ZPL that would be stored on the printer to allow users to print directly from the printer through custom menu in WML.

I'm having no problems creating custom menu, sending it to the printer and calling for the said ZPL file, but the printer is not asking for keyboard input when it should.
Example ZPL code:

```
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA
^PW437
^FT40,167^A0N,25,24^FH\^FN1"EXAMPLE2"^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

When printing from Print Station option on the printer, printer correctly asks for the value of EXAMPLE2, when calling ZPL from custom menu, it just defaults to nothing and prints as there was no input.

Does anyone ever worked with something similar?
Ideally I would need 3 inputs from the barcode scanner to generate a very simple label. Would like to do it with printer and scanner alone if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with a similar issue.
Zebra support suggested to read WML from printer and see/modify them to create my own Print Station.
PrintStation is in `z:TOOLS.WML`
You can read files (send to host) with this SGD command
`{}{"file.type":"Z:TOOLS.WML"}`